# What are the homology groups of these spaces as $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$-module?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $P_1=\mathbb{RP}^n$ and $P_2 =S^1 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$. I want to compute $H_i (\tilde{P}_1)$ and $H_i (\tilde{P}_2)$ as $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$-modules.

**My try:** We know that $\tilde{P}_1=S^n$ and $\tilde{P}_2=S^2$. So $H_i (\tilde{P}_1)=0$ for $i\neq n$ and $H_n (\tilde{P}_1)=\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Also we have So $H_i (\tilde{P}_2)=0$ for $i\neq 2$ and $H_2 (\tilde{P}_2)=\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module. On the other hand, $\pi_1 (P_1)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\pi_1 (P_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. My problem is that I don't know how to compute $H_i (\tilde{P}_1)$ and $H_i (\tilde{P}_2)$ as $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$-modules.

Here $\tilde{P}$ denotes the universal covering space of $P$.

Comment: Your computation of homology of projective space is incorrect.

Comment: @IDC I didn't compute the homology of projective space . I computed the homology of its universal covering space.

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: @IDC No problem. It's my wrong. I have to introduce the symbol $\tilde{P}$. I'll just edit it.